# Time format Validation in ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I'm Creating Excel file using ClosedXMl, and want to set alert message on entering Time format other than "HH:MM".
I have tried below code but after entering "1" also it's not showing error message but same is working fine for Date format.

```
       ws.Cell("D7").Style.NumberFormat.Format = "hh-mm";
       ws.Cell("D7").DataValidation.Time.EqualOrGreaterThan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
       ws.Cell("D7").SetDataValidation().ErrorStyle = XLErrorStyle.Stop;
       ws.Cell("D7").SetDataValidation().ErrorMessage = "Date Format HH MM";
```

code which is working for Date(Alert message get popup aftering entering 1)

```
      ws.Cell("T5").Style.NumberFormat.Format = "dd-mmm-yyyy";
      ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().Date.EqualOrGreaterThan(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));
      ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().ErrorStyle = XLErrorStyle.Stop;
      ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().ErrorMessage = "Date Format DD MMM YYYY";
```

Comment: Is this even possible in Excel?

Comment: yes,it is working for "Date" format but i want for "Time" format also.

Comment: @Tejashree can you try using DateTime, like `SetDataValidation().DateTime` for validating time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is no Time property for EqualOrGreaterThan method of Time in `DataValidation.Time.EqualOrGreaterThan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));`. But try the below method.

One thing you can do is that you can put time along with date in the date validation.

```
  ws.Cell("T5").Style.NumberFormat.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
  ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().Date.EqualOrGreaterThan(new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)); // first 
  ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().ErrorStyle = XLErrorStyle.Stop;
  ws.Cell("T5").SetDataValidation().ErrorMessage = "Date Format DD MMM YYYY HH mm ss";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but my requirement is Cell will contain time only. After entering Character it shows Error message that only HH:MM format is allowed but is doesn't work for integers value and it replace integers with 00:00.

Comment: can you use cell style and NumberFormat, eg `sheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";`